# How to solve client registration in peer to peer network?

Tags: node.js, session, socket.io, p2p, peer

## Background

I want to make my own kind of peer 2 peer network (needs to be custom). I'm making it using SocketIO, it works fine. First I made it using a Client->Server architecture, however it was not ideal for my purposes.

## Current situation

Now, I came up on a problem when building the peer 2 peer version. After all clients are connected, they need to know each other (ID+hostname). In order to do this, I came up with the following plan.

1. Client connects to Socket IO in group (simulatenously with some other devices), gets added into a session pool with other bound clients (done using intermediate NodeJS router).
2. Every new client broadcasts `newClient` signal.
3. Every client broadcasts ID+device data to others upon initial joining.

Until here, everything is fine and working.

4. Whenever a client receives the `newClient` signal, step 3 is repeated, so in case devices join the session after the initial session in step 1 was created, the new device also receives the client data from existing devices.

## Problem

If there is a session with n devices, **step 3 could occur [image: amount] times** (for`x > 2` and element of N).

For 100 clients, step 3 would **occur 5153 times.** Which is quite high.

**Is there any smarter way in order for the device data to be broadcasted less and still have all connected devices know each other?**

Answer (score 3):

You can use a DHT ([Distributed Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table)) structure in which each node of your network is identified by a key (deterministic hash based on your application ID+device) and the nodes are indexed by their hash.

One such a structure is a [chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(peer-to-peer)) in which all nodes are organized in a circular structue of predetermined maximum size N=2^m with a successor function (S(n) = n+1 ; S(2^m) = 0). Each node's position in this circle is given by its hash. Each node keeps a list of m *fingers* : a list of closest successors at a distance 2^0, … 2^m from the node's own position. When one node enters the network it connects to any entrypoint in the network (at least one known node in the network) and then finds its first successor (in time O(N)) by following the closest node in the entrypoint's finger table and so on. Finally only adjacent nodes update their finger tables.

Here is paper describing an algorithm for [Efficient Broadcast in Structured P2P Networks](https://www.sics.se/~seif/Publications/paper3.pdf) which uses a chord like structure.

Hope this helps.